# Relative urls vs Protocol-relative URLs

Tags: url

I am just wondering if I use a relative URL as follows:

```
"/myfolder"
```

It will change to

```
mydomain/myfolder
```

But does it also maintain if the root is HTTP or HTTPS similar to the `"//"` approach.

i.e. if the page loading my relative URL `/myfolder` has HTTPS will this change to

```
"https://mydomain/myfolder"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Yes.

*Relative references* are always applied against a [*base URI*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.1) ([see how](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2)).

In HTML5, the [*document base URL*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#document-base-url) is, in the common case (i.e., no [`base` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#the-base-element), no [`iframe`-`srcdoc` document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#an-iframe-srcdoc-document), no [`about:blank`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#about:blank)), [*the document's address*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-document%27s-address).

So if you have a document at `http://example.com/foo`, a link with the relative reference `/bar` will link to the URL `http://example.com/bar`. And if the document is at `https://example.com/foo`, it will link to `https://example.com/bar`.